# Нормально ли спросить "сколько время"?

Tags: выражения

Пусть неправильно по грамматике, но, если хочешь узнать где-то время, то нормально ли спросить "сколько время"? Меня не столько волнует граммотность, сколько естественно ли это звучит в повседневной речи. Может это какой-то региональный сленг?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: It's a slang. Usually when people don't care about being polite and/or correct in language. Correct is "Который час?". "Сколько времени ..." should be used when you are asking about longevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нормально ли спросить "сколько время"

If by "normal" you mean "are there people who see nothing wrong with this construct", then yes, there are lots of people who talk like that and see nothing wrong with this construct.

It's not uncommon to hear this phrase in live speech, and it's being mentioned in the corpus as early as 1866, in a direct speech of one of Leskov's characters.

The use of this phrase is, however, discouraged by most style guides. This phrase would not make it through proofreading and copy-editing pipeline of most media which do proofreading and copy-editing.

People, who are taking their clues about grammar mostly from printed media, would treat this phrase as a solecism, "a phrase that transgresses the rules of grammar"

> Может это какой-то региональный сленг

As far as I can judge, it's not, it's used all over Russia and other Russian-speaking territories.

In Nizhny Novgorod and its vicinity, the answer to that could be *без пять десять* (instead of *без пяти десять*) which is a regionalism.

Comment: +1 but I expected you to mention "который час?" as a recommended alternative. It's not perfectly clear from the question whether the OP is aware of this or not...  > без пять десять - :) In Yaroslavl region you might get an answer *без пятнадцати*, assuming that you can't be *that* stupid as to not to be aware of the hour))

Comment: @tum_ just in case, *без пять десять* means 9:55 in Nizhegorodian

Comment: I am aware of all the alternatives; this question comes from a girl in Moscow who accused me of "making up" the phrase and claimed to have never heard it in her entire life, but in Rostov everyone I know says "сколько время"

Comment: Yes, I got it. I might even have heard this, so not surprised at all. Eh, actually, I believe, my father used to say *"без пять минут десять"*, he was from Ivanovo/Kostroma border...

Comment: @Kanga_Roo You'd better add this additional info into your question text. It's always more convenient to readers to see all relevant information in the question itself.